# Potential inside metal sphere in field of external charge

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, conductors, method-of-images

If a have a arrangement like-( Where r is radius of hollow conducting sphere with centre C and Q is point charge)

[image]

Then what is potential at any point between P and C?

I think first we need to find Potential at P-
$$V_P=\frac{Kq_{in}}{r}+\frac{KQ}{3r}$$ where $q_{in}$ is induced charge on the sphere surface. Now as we go inside the sphere this potential should remain constant because net electric field inside a conducting hollow sphere is always 0 and it should be same at centre too i.e at C.

But somewhere in a book while solving a problem related to the same situation i found-"*Potential at C due to Q and induced charges is* $V_c =\frac{kQ}{2r}$ *which is just due to Q* *[Potential at C due to induced charges is zero]*"

I have been studying the concept over and over but i can't find my mistake, where i interpreted this wrong?

Comment: Your formula for $V_p$ is incorrect because it assumes that the induced charge on the sphere is uniformly distributed, which it is not.

Comment: Specifically, the$ \frac{Kq_{in}}{r}$ is wrong (should be  $\frac{KQ}{6r}$), see derivation in my answer below.

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus I think the formula for Vp is incorrect because gauss law isn't useful in this situation coz EdA cos(theta) does not equal EdA. Is it what it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At any point $P$ inside the sphere, let the superposed electric field be
$$\vec{E_P} = \vec{E}_{PQ} + \vec{E}_{PI}$$
where
$\vec{E}_{PQ}$ means electric field at $P$ due to $Q$ and
$\vec{E}_{PI}$ means electric field at $P$ due to all of the induced charges on the sphere.

Then,
\begin{align*}
V_P = - \int_\infty^P \vec{E_P} \cdot d\vec{l} &= - \int_\infty^P  \vec{E}_{PQ} \cdot d\vec{l} - \int_\infty^P \vec{E}_{PI} \cdot d\vec{l} \\
&= V_{PQ} + V_{PI}
\end{align*}
where
$V_{PQ}$ means potential at $P$ due to $Q$ and
$V_{PI}$ means **sum of potential** at $P$ due to all of the induced charges on the sphere.

For point $C$ (the center of sphere)
\begin{align*}
V_{CQ} &= \frac{kq}{2r} \\
V_{CI} &= \sum_i^{\text{all induced charges on the sphere}} \frac{kq_i}{r} = 0 \\
V_C &= V_{CQ} + V_{CI}\\
&= \frac{kq}{2r}
\end{align*}
Notice above that $V_{CI}$ is zero due to the assumption that the sphere is neutral to start with, so that the sum of all induced $q_i$ should be zero (conservation of charge).

Now consider point P as located in OP's diagram.
Since potentials of any two points inside the sphere are the same, and since $P$ and $C$ are both in the sphere,
\begin{align*}
V_P &= V_C \\
V_{PQ} + V_{PI} &= \frac{kq}{2r} \\
\frac{kq}{3r} + V_{PI} &= \frac{kq}{2r} \\
V_{PI} &= \frac{kq}{6r}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  following from the derivation if V{P} = V{PQ} +V{PI}-------(1) for all points P, let take it as 'x' distance away from centre along line PQ. Then taking your results V{P}= Kq/2r ; V{PI} = kq/6r; and lastly V{PQ}= Kq/(2r-x) ;  putting results in eqn(1) i think that since everything beside 'x' will be constant the eqn can be solved for 'x' but x can be any value between 0<x<r. Why the two results does not satisfy each other?

Comment: For any point $P$ in the sphere, $V_{PQ} + V_{PI} = \frac{kq}{2r}$. As you vary the location of $P$ within the sphere, then $V_{PI}$ varies accordingly such that the sum is always $V_{PQ} + V_{PI} = \frac{kq}{2r}$. In other words, don't treat $V_{PI}$ as a constant.